# Strange intellisense tab behaviour

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I use Visual Code (1.13.1) on a Mac (10.12.5). I have Color Picker (0.4.1), gitlens (4.1.3) and vscode-database (1.2.0) installed extensions.

Why I press tab to move away from some code that I have already intellisense completed, it changes the entire code block to some odd html/xml formatting...:
[image: Before]

My cursor (you can't see it in the screen shot, is immediately after `company_id` - and when I press TAB to move to inline with the `=` in the line above it, it changes to this:
[image: After]

Has anyone got any clues as to what I need to turn off for this behaviour to cease?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to:

> File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts

find **emmet.expandAbbreviation** *first thing that uses tab* and change or delete that shortcut